# Windows Server 2012 locking itself after 10 seconds

Tags: windows, configuration

Windows Server 2012 Standard 64bit

It doesn't matter if I'm using this server through mstsc, locally or via any third party remote software (LogMeIn), this machine is locking itself after 10 seconds of inactivity, and it asks for the user's password every time.

What really bugs me is that there no way to set Windows to lock/enter screensaver after 10 seconds, only after at least 60 seconds.

I searched google, microsoft forums, etc, but couldn't find anything related to this problem.

I have even tried disabling, by GPO, the screensaver on this machine, but it didn't work. After 10 seconds, the screen becomes black and I have 1 second to do something, or it will ask for my password again.

Any help appreciated.

Thank you!

EDIT: I'd like to add as well that any user logged in this server is having the same problem, even with a newly created profile folder.